# Jquery Ajax simple application: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm pulling my hair out here.  I keep getting "missing ) after argument list" on my final line of code.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my concatenation but I can't figure it out.  It's jQuery with jQuery UI: a simple slider.  User increases the amount on the slider and the available flights at that amount are displayed.  Clicking on the available flight shows the duration:

```
  $(document.ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/all_work_july_6/javascript_start_here/flights.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var counter = 0;
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $("#flightList").append('<li ' + 'id="flight' + counter + '"' + ' class="flightLi">' + value['trip'] + '<span class="hiddenPrice">' + value['price'] + '</span></li>');

        counter++;
        });
    }


});

$("#priceSlider").slider({
orientation: "vertical",
min: 200,
max: 1650,
step: 200,
value: 1650,
slide: function(event, uiElement){
    $("#flightDetails").html("<p>Flight Details</p>").addClass("hidden");
    var numRegex = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    var inputNum = uiElement.value;
    var strNum = inputNum.toString();
    strNum = strNum.replace(numRegex, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    $("#spanPrice").text(strNum);
    $("#inputPrice").val(uiElement.value);
    $(".hiddenPrice").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() > inputNum){
            $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
        }
        else if($(this).text() < inputNum){
            $(this).parent().removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
}

});

$(".flightLi").on('click', function(){
$("#flightDetails").html("<p>Flight Details</p>").addClass("hidden");
var myId = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/all_work_july_6/javascript_start_here/details.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "flightID": myId },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#flightDetails").removeClass("hidden").append('<ul>' + '<li class="detailsLi">Trip Duration: ' + data['duration'] + '</li>' + '</ul>');

        }

    });
});
});
```

Comment: `)` is missing in `$(document)`

Comment: You should remove each block of code and see when the error is going so that you can find out where the error is then should fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the first line, Missing `)`  in `$(document`

```
//$(document.ready(function(){ You had this. ) is missing

$(document).ready(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing )in $(document

Replace $(document to $(document)

Comment: Thanks Marcos!  Wow, I can't believe how long I debugged for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/spencerdcarlson/y4h9rvea/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// mocked response from flights.php
var data = {
  json: $.toJSON({0: {trip: "Hawaii", price: "1000"} }),
  delay: 3
}

// AJAX post to "fllights.php" and process the response
$.ajax({
  url:"/echo/json/", // JSfiddle Echo API - http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html
  data:data,
  type:"POST",
  success:function(data){
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      var li = "<li id='flight"+counter+"'"+" class='flightLi'>"+value['trip']+"<span class='hiddenPrice'>"+value['price']+"</span></li>";
      $('#flightList').append(li);
      addListener();    // add the onClick listener to the newly created <li> item. 
      counter++;            // You could also pass in the id attribute to this method 
      });
    }
});

// Slider
$("#priceSlider").slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  min: 200,
  max: 1650,
  step: 200,
  value: 1650,
  slide: function(event, uiElement){
    $("#flightDetails").html("<p>Flight Details</p>").addClass("hidden");
    var numRegex = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    var inputNum = uiElement.value;
    var strNum = inputNum.toString();
    strNum = strNum.replace(numRegex, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    $("#spanPrice").text(strNum);
    $("#inputPrice").val(uiElement.value);
    $(".hiddenPrice").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() > inputNum){
        $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
      }
      else if($(this).text() < inputNum){
        $(this).parent().removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
  }
});

// moked response from details.php for "flightID": myId
data = {
  json: $.toJSON({duration: '1000 hrs'}),
  delay: 1
}


// wraper method to only add the onClick listner after the new <li> is inserted to the DOM
function addListener(){
  // List item onClick AJAX
  $(".flightLi").one( "click", function() { // Using the .one method to only add the onClick event listener once
    $("#flightDetails").html("<p>Flight Details</p>").addClass("hidden");
    console.log("Flight id: "+$(this).attr("id"));
    $.ajax({
      url:"/echo/json/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        var li = "<ul><li class='detailsLi'>Trip Duration: "+data['duration']+"</li></ul>";
        $("#flightDetails").removeClass("hidden").append(li);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Origional code 
// This doesn't work due to the fact that the <li> item 
// in the flightList list is inserted to the the DOM after the intital load
// you can also bind the event at the document level see this post http://bit.ly/1S0H2q0

// $(".flightLi").on('click', function(){
//   $("#flightDetails").html("<p>Flight Details</p>").addClass("hidden");
//   console.log("Flight id: "+$(this).attr("id"));
//   $.ajax({
//     url:"/echo/json/",
//     dataType: "json",
//     data: data,
//     type: "POST",
//     success: function(data) {
//       var li = "<ul><li class='detailsLi'>Trip Duration: "+data['duration']+"</li></ul>";
//       $("#flightDetails").removeClass("hidden").append(li);
//     }
//   });
// });

});
```

A few things I noticed while going through your code:

- The `$("#flightDetails").html("<p>Flight Details</p>").addClass("hidden");` line is actually removing the *Trip Duration:* content because it completely replaces the html inside of the *#flightDetails* element. - This might be intentional
- Adding the `onClick` event listener to the newly created `<li>` elements must be done at the document level, or from inside of the call back that actually injects them into the DOM. I chose to implement the call back method. See [this post](http://bit.ly/1S0H2q0) for adding the listener at the document level
- Adding the event listener from inside of the call back method opens up the issue of possibly adding the event listener to the same element multiple times. This can result in an onClick event firing multiple times per one trigger. Again you must either add the event at the document level, or use the `one` method to only add the event once. See the [JQuery.one documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Hi Dooagain,  Thanks for the follow up!  I ended up figuring this out on my own yesterday, and i'm glad I did as I always find de-bugging to be a great learning exercise!  As I discovered, anything created dynamically requires a different approach (I studied the .on() function a bit more closely).  This got things working for me:                                  $('#flightList').on( "click", "li.flightLi", function(){